# Diversifying search results in ElasticSearch 7.5

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-7

I have a search-index containing products of different catalogs. Now when I search for a given search-term quite often results like the following one are being returned:

```
Catalog 1 - Product 1
Catalog 1 - Product 2
Catalog 1 - Product 3
...
Catalog 1 - Product x
Catalog 2 - Product 1
...
```

This is not optimal, as I want to point the user to other catalogs, also, without having him to browse through multiple pages of search-results containing all products of the same catalog. So I tried to use the [diversified_sampler-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-diversified-sampler-aggregation.html) which, in conjunction with a child [top_hits-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html), seemed to be exactly the solution, I want:

```
POST /myIndex/_search?typed_keys=true
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "title^2",
        "description^2",
        "descriptionOriginal^0.01"
      ],
      "query": "*someSearchTerm*"
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "aggDiversifiedSampler": {
      "diversified_sampler": {
        "shard_size": 100000,
        "field": "catalogId",
        "max_docs_per_value": 3
      },
      "aggs": {
        "aggTopHits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "from": 0,
            "size": 50,
            "sort": [
              {
                "_score": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Paging is being done through the "size" and "from" properties of the inner top_hits-aggregation. The search-results can be fetched from the values-collection of the inner top_hits-aggregation - therefore I set the size of the query itself to 0.

This seems to work - at a first glance, but having a closer look at the results, reveals, that not all search-results are being returned. The results now look like this:

```
Catalog 1 - Product 1
Catalog 1 - Product 2
Catalog 1 - Product 3
Catalog 2 - Product 1
Catalog 2 - Product 2
Catalog 2 - Product 3
...
Catalog x - Product 1
Catalog x - Product 2
Catalog x - Product 3
```

...and then it ends.

It seems, that the diversified_sampler does not warp-around after reaching the last catalog, and so further results from the single catalogs won't appear. What I want is something like this:

```
Catalog 1 - Product 1
Catalog 1 - Product 2
Catalog 1 - Product 3
Catalog 2 - Product 1
Catalog 2 - Product 2
Catalog 2 - Product 3
...
Catalog x - Product 1
Catalog x - Product 2
Catalog x - Product 3
Catalog 1 - Product 4
Catalog 1 - Product 5
Catalog 1 - Product 6
Catalog 2 - Product 4
Catalog 2 - Product 5
Catalog 2 - Product 6
...
```

Any ideas? My technique using the diversified_sampler is not set into stone, but I couldn't come up with something else. Some fancy script-based sorting of the query maybe? Don't know. Client-based reordering is not an option, because I don't want the elasticsearch-wise paging get broken. I need the paging to keep the performance up - the search-index is about 18GB containing 900k documents...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution without the diversified_sampler-aggregation using scripted sorting:

```
POST /myIndex/_search?typed_keys=true
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "title^2",
        "description^2",
        "descriptionOriginal^0.01"
      ],
      "query": "*someSearchTerm*"
    }
  },
  "sort": [{
      "_script": {
        "script": {
          "source": "Math.round(_score / params.fuzziness) * params.fuzziness",
          "params": {
            "fuzziness": 2
          }
        },
        "type": "number",
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }, {
      "_script": {
        "script": {
          "source": "if(doc['catalogId'].value != params.cid) {params.cid=doc['catalogId'].value;params.sort=0;return params.count=0;} else {return (++params.count % params.grpSize == 0) ?++params.sort : params.sort;}",
          "params": {
            "cid": 0,
            "sort": 0,
            "count": 0,
            "grpSize": 3
          }
        },
        "type": "number",
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }, {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In the first scripted-sort I pre-sort my documents, so that results within a certain _score-range fall together. This is being controlled by the fuzziness-parameter. Then I sort within these ranges using a script-sort so that always the next 3 (controlled by param grpSize) documents per catalog-id are taken and then incrementing the sort-order. (Don't know if it is dangerous to use script-params as a "global"-variables...I feel a little bit uncomfortable with that...)

Here is the script in a more readable representation:

```
if(doc['catalogId'].value != params.cid) {
  params.cid = doc['catalogId'].value;
  params.sort = 0;
  return params.count = 0;
} else {
  return (++params.count % params.grpSize == 0) ? ++params.sort : params.sort;
}
```

Last but not least the documents with the same _score-range and sort-order are being sorted by their real _score.

The solution doesn't involve a real performance-impact (at least on my index) and delivers quite the results, i wanted.

Please feel free to post ideas and optimizations!